# p:ajax rowSelect event is not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I have a p:dataTable with selectionMode "single". If a row is selected a listener should be called in the backing bean. No difficulty... however when I tried the code on Internet Explorer 9, the rowSelect event is never called. Usually I am using Firefox and Chrome, where everything is working normally (the events are called), so the problem only occurs on Internet Explorer. The strange thing is that I couldn't find further entries in forums about this problem so far. I am using primefaces-4.0 and jsf-2.2.4 (Mojarra)

Here is the xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="someId" var="patients" value="#{homeBean.listData.patients}" rowKey="#{patients.pid}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{homeBean.onPatientSelect}" />
    <p:column headerText="PID">...</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and the related Java code:

```
public void onPatientSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    //I do not reach this with Internet Explorer
}
```

I'm really stuck here, has anyone an idea where the problem may lie?

Comment: Press F12 on IE and see what document mode is running in ??